# How to restrict SSH access outside of LAN?

Tags: ssh, security-theater

We have several dedicated servers.

We need to ensure "**root**" user **can not be accessible through SSH outside of LAN**.

I have searched and found the followings #

- http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=20826
- http://raspi.tv/tag/disable-password-login-for-ssh
- http://kb.eukhost.com/steps-to-change-ssh-port-of-a-server/
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html

> We need exactly the root user will be unable to access outside of LAN.
>   but other users will be accessible outside of LAN. 
>   Because other users can do their work only within their scope.

**Our OS details**

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-308.4.1.el5PAE (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)) #1 SMP Tue Apr 17 17:47:38 EDT 2012
```

Please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Firstly, configuration questions are not really on-topic here at Sec.SE. Secondly, have you done **ANY** research on the topic at all? A simple Google search will show you several ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @TerryChia, thanks for comment. I have edited my answer as your comment. I searched this topic on internet, but i didn't get the exact solution. please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/310459/allowgroups-and-match-address-for-ssh, http://serverfault.com/questions/89795/restrict-root-ssh-from-all-but-one-ip-hostname

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what you want, I googled: only allow root ssh lan

First hit...
http://drsavoye.blogspot.com/2010/06/enable-root-login-from-lan-only.html

> On Linux, edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config. On Macs, edit /etc/sshd_config.
>   Locate the line that defines PermitRootLogin, uncomment if it is
>   commented out, and change its value to yes.
>
> On a separate line, add the following:
>
> Match Address 192.168.2.*,127.0.0.1
>         PermitRootLogin yes

Of course, changing 192.168.2 to match your LAN subnet.

Comment: The main PermitRootLogin option should be *no* (only the second one should by *yes*).